# C++11 using std::equal_range with custom comparison function

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this example

(*Note that this is just something I made up to illustrate the problem. I am well aware there are more efficient ways to parse an arithmetic expression and though the subject is fascinating, this has nothing to do with my actual question. It's just a semi-realistic example, if I might say so.*
*I agree the parser thing might make the question seem more complicated, but I could not think of a more abstract example*).

Assume you want to do a simple expression parser. You will get bits of strings from a tokenizer, some of them being possibly ambiguous.

For instance, the string "-" could represent an unary minus or a binary minus.

Assume you want to get all possible meanings for string "-".

You could do as follows:

1) define a sorted array describing all possible operators

```
// types of operators
enum class opType: char { unary, lasso, rasso, none };

// operator descriptors
struct opDesc {
    string symbol;
    opType type;
    char   priority;

    // partial order comparison
    bool operator< (const opDesc& a) const
    {
        // unary operators first
        if (symbol == a.symbol) return type < a.type;
        return symbol < a.symbol;
    }

    // comparison with strings
    static bool comp_desc_str (const opDesc& a, const string& s)
    {
        return a.symbol < s;
    }
    static bool comp_str_desc (const string& s, const opDesc& a)
    {
        return s < a.symbol;
    }
};

static opDesc op_descriptors[] = {
    { "+" , opType::unary, 8 }, // unary +
    { "-" , opType::unary, 8 }, // unary -
    { "*" , opType::lasso, 6 }, // multiplication
    { "/" , opType::lasso, 6 }, // division
    { "+" , opType::lasso, 5 }, // addition
    { "-" , opType::lasso, 5 }, // substraction
};
```

2) use `std::equal_range` to get all possible matches for a given string

```
// sort descriptors by value and type
sort(begin(op_descriptors), end(op_descriptors));

// do some searches
string patterns[] = { "+", "-", ">>", "**" };

for (string s : patterns)
{
    pair<opDesc*, opDesc*> ops;

    ops = equal_range(
        std::begin(op_descriptors), 
        std::end  (op_descriptors), 
        s,
        opDesc::comp_desc_str);

    cout << s <<": "<< ops.first[0] << ops.second[-1] << endl;
}
```

This code won't compile, complaining about `opDesc::comp_desc_str` (it expects parameters the other way around, i.e. `string` first, `opDesc` next).

If I try to replace the function with a version that takes its arguments in reverse order:

```
ops = equal_range(
    std::begin(op_descriptors), 
    std::end  (op_descriptors), 
    s,
    opDesc::comp_str_desc);
```

it won't compile either, complaining about parameters being yet again in the wrong order (at some other point of the algorithm).

This code, however, will work ([see a live version here](http://ideone.com/CPUAfW))

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// types of operators
enum class opType: char { unary, lasso, rasso, none };

// operator descriptors
struct opDesc {
    string symbol;
    opType type;
    char   priority;

    // partial order comparison
    bool operator< (const opDesc& a) const
    {
        // unary operators first
        if (symbol == a.symbol) return type < a.type;
        return symbol < a.symbol;
    }

    // comparison with strings
    static bool comp_desc_str (const opDesc& a, const string& s)
    {
        return a.symbol < s;
    }
    static bool comp_str_desc (const string& s, const opDesc& a)
    {
        return s < a.symbol;
    }

    // display
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const opDesc& op);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const opDesc& op)
{
    os << op.symbol << "[" << (int)op.type << ":" << (int)op.priority << "]";
    return os;
}

static opDesc op_descriptors[] = {
    { "+" , opType::unary, 8 }, // unary +
    { "-" , opType::unary, 8 }, // unary -
    { "~" , opType::unary, 8 }, // bitwise not
    { "**", opType::rasso, 7 }, // power
    { "*" , opType::lasso, 6 }, // multiplication
    { "/" , opType::lasso, 6 }, // division
    { "%" , opType::lasso, 6 }, // remainder
    { "+" , opType::lasso, 5 }, // addition
    { "-" , opType::lasso, 5 }, // substraction
    { "<<", opType::lasso, 4 }, // left shift
    { ">>", opType::lasso, 4 }, // right shift
    { "&" , opType::lasso, 3 }, // bitwise and
    { "^" , opType::lasso, 2 }, // bitwise xor
    { "|" , opType::lasso, 1 }, // bitwise or 
    { "(" , opType::none , 0 }, // braces
    { ")" , opType::none , 0 }
};

int main(void)
{
    // sort descriptors by value and type
    sort(begin(op_descriptors), end(op_descriptors));

    // do some searches
    string patterns[] = { "+", "-", ">>", "**" };

    for (string s : patterns)
    {
        pair<opDesc*, opDesc*> ops;
        // this won't work
        /*
        ops = equal_range(
            std::begin(op_descriptors), 
            std::end  (op_descriptors), 
            s,
            opDesc::comp_desc_str or opDesc::comp_str_desc);
        */
        // this works
        ops.first = lower_bound(
            std::begin(op_descriptors), 
            std::end  (op_descriptors), 
            s, opDesc::comp_desc_str);
        ops.second = upper_bound(
            std::begin(op_descriptors), 
            std::end  (op_descriptors), 
            s, opDesc::comp_str_desc);
        cout << s <<": "<< ops.first[0] << ops.second[-1] << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
+: +[0:8]+[1:5]     // unary and binary "-" operators found
-: -[0:8]-[1:5]     // same thing for "+"
>>: >>[1:4]>>[1:4]  // first == second when there is only
**: **[2:7]**[2:7]  // one version of the operator
```

**I tried this code on VisualC++ 2013 and g++ with the same results**
(only the obfuscation of the template error messages vary).

#### Questions

- is there a particular reason why `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` should require two different custom comparison functions?
- is there a workaround for MSVC throwing a bogus error in debug build when using functors to work around the problem?
- is there a definite workaround for this problem (i.e. using `equal_range` as intended instead of doing the job twice **and** make it compile in debug mode on Visual C++ 2013)?

Comment: I think you should use the same comparison function both for the equal_range and sort

Comment: @Daniele the array order is not based on the same function on purpose (the array is sorted lexicographically with operator arity as a secondary criterion), and besides the way the array is sorted will not help the compiler using the proper comparison function.

Comment: I see, could you use a temporary opDesc variable? in this way you can have `static bool comp_str_desc (const opDesc& s, const opDesc& a)`

Comment: @Daniele I sure could, but I don't want to :). Creating a dummy variable just to make the bloody template work is not what I call an acceptable solution.

Comment: If your sorting predicate doesn't result in the same _weak total ordering_ then your `equal_range` lookup will result in [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @sehe I know that, but this is not the problem here.

Comment: There isn't any ambiguity between binary infix and unary prefix operators if your parser has any state at all: if you just finished parsing a term (a number, or possibly a close-paren), then the next operator has to be binary; otherwise it has to be unary.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yep, but this has nothing to do with my question. The proper way of parsing an expression is to use a lexer generator anyway. I only took this as a more or less realistic example of use for std::equal_range.

Comment: @kuroineko This question would significantly improve if you throw out all the parser stuff and concentrate on the core of the problem.

Comment: @prm agreed, but I can't think of a way to do a shorter compilable example. Any idea?

Comment: BTW: what is the runtime(?) error of MSVC 2013 in debug ?

Comment: @Jarod42 it's a compile error. The complete vomit is 3000 characters long, but the short version boils down to `error C2664: 'bool opDesc::comp::operator ()(const opDesc &,const std::string &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'opDesc' to 'const std::string &'`. I suspect the check is made to make sure the comparison defines a total order, which is silly since the whole point of this API is to work on partially ordered structures.

Comment: Then, as Kristian Duske does, maybe providing `operator () (const opDesc&, const opDesc&)` and `(const string&, const string&)` solves that in debug build...

Comment: @Jarod42 Well yes, it should, but adding dead **and** meaningless code (I mean, comparing 2 opDescs in this context is plain wrong) just to make the thing compile seems a rather convoluted thing to do, even if that code will never be instanciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own answer, only summarizing other contributions, notably Jarod42's:

#### Why the two comparisons

The algorithm of `equal_range` requires both `>` and `<` comparisons between internal (`opDesc` in this example) and foreign (`std::string`) types.

You can't deduce `a<b` from `!(b<a)`, because of the `==` case, so you have to provide two different comparators.

Functionnally, you could pick any working combination of comparison operations, for instance `<` and `>` or `<` and `<=`, but the std:: guys settled for a fixed `<` comparison with arguments swapped around, which is a choice dictated by the signature of the function: it only has to define a `(type, foreign type)` and a `(foreign type, type)` variant.

`lower_bound` only requires `<` (expressed as `type < foreigh type`) while `upper_bound` only requires `>` (expressed as `foreign type < type`), so both can work with a single function, but `equal_range` must have access to both prototypes.

#### The way to do it

The practical solution is to define a function object aka functor to do the job:

```
// operator descriptors
struct opDesc {
    string symbol;
    opType type;
    char   priority;

    // partial order comparison
    bool operator< (const opDesc& a) const
    {
        // unary operators first
        if (symbol == a.symbol) return type < a.type;
        return symbol < a.symbol;
    }

    // functor to compare with strings
    struct comp
    {
        bool operator() (const opDesc& a, const std::string& b) const
        {
           return a.symbol < b;
        }

        bool operator() (const std::string& a, const opDesc& b) const
        {
           return a < b.symbol;
        }
    };
```

and use it like so:

```
pair<opDesc*, opDesc*> ops;
ops = equal_range(
    std::begin(op_descriptors), 
    std::end  (op_descriptors), 
    s,
    opDesc::comp()); // <- functor to provide two different comparison functions
```

#### MSVC bug

Besides, this won't compile on MSVC++ 2013 due to an obscure paranoid check enabled only in debug mode. The release version will compile fine, as will the code in g++ regardless of debug level.

Judging from the cryptic names used, it seems the template checks whether the comparison defines a total order (which it shouldn't since the whole point of this API is to work on partially ordered structures).

My current (ugly) workaround is to disable some internal debug flag:

```
#if (defined _MSC_VER && defined _DEBUG)
#define _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL 1
#endif // _MSC_VER && _DEBUG
```

prior to including std:: headers

Another possible workaround suggested by Jarod42 is to define the missing comparison function.

```
    // functor to compare with strings
    struct comp
    {
        bool operator() (const opDesc& a, const std::string& b)
        { return a.symbol < b; }
        bool operator() (const std::string& a, const opDesc& b)
        { return a < b.symbol; }

        // just to make Microsoft Visual C++ happy when compiling in debug mode
        bool operator() (const opDesc& a, const opDesc& b)
        { assert(false); return false; }
    };
```

Comment: The requirement is not useless. How do you write `comp_str_desc` using only `comp_desc_str` ?

Comment: I mean, the internal template code could simply reorder the parameters itself, instead of requiring the user to to it, or did I miss something?

Comment: I mean the algo requires to compute `b < a`, how do you write it with `a < b` only ? `!(a < b)` -> `(b <= a)` which is not the same... So you may require to have a `equalTo` (or `differentTo`). Requiring only `a < b` and `b < a` seems cleaner ans less restrictive.

Comment: Right, I get it now. Whish the C++ guys were a tad bit more explicit, but that would ruin the whole "if you're too stupid then don't even come near C++" philosophy. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: About your wording, `operator >` is not required, only `operator <` is required. (but it is better to provide the other once we provide one).

Comment: @Jarod42 I rephrased my answer. Are you OK with the last version?

Answer (score 6):

`std::lower_bound` requires `comp(*it, val)` whereas `std::upper_bound` requires `comp(val, *it)`.

So your `comp` functor have to provide both `bool operator () (const opDesc& a, const string& s) const` and `bool operator ()(const string& s, const opDesc& a) const`.

So, you may use following comp functor:

```
struct lessOpDescWithString
{
    bool operator () (const opDesc& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
       return opDesc::comp_desc_str(lhs, rhs);
    }

    bool operator () (const std::string& lhs, const opDesc& rhs) const {
       return opDesc::comp_str_desc(lhs, rhs);
    }
};
```

Comment: well I got it now, but I will select my own answer just to summarize the various points you answered. Thanks a lot for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` will use a binary search on your sorted array and must be able to compare `obDesc` to `std::string` and vice versa. I would suggest making a comparator like

```
struct obDescStrCmp {
    bool operator()(const opDesc& lhs, const opDesc& rhs) const {
       // code to compare obDesc to opDesc
    }

    bool operator()(const opDesc& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
       // code to compare obDesc to std::string
    }

    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const opDesc& rhs) const {
       // code to compare std::string to opDesc
    }

    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
       // code to compare std::string to std::string
       // I'm not sure if this is really necessary.
    }
};
```

and pass it to your std algorithm of choice instead of relying on the operators defined in your `opDesc` struct. The compiler should select the correct overload based on the actual order of parameters in the implementations of the std algorithms.

Edit: Replace `operator<` with `operator()` to make the struct callable.

Comment: I see what you mean: using a function object to do the job. However, your code does not do that.

Comment: well the last parameter of `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `equal_range` must be a function that does the comparison between the two types in any order, not an `operator<`.

Comment: You can pass a callable to these algorithms. In this case, that would be an instance of the struct outlined in my answer.

Comment: Well that would require to instantiate yet another dummy just to make the bloody template behave, or did I miss something? Could you show me an example of std::equal_range invokation using this technique?

Comment: Ah, OK, that's your good old functor now. But only the `(const opDesc& lhs, const std::string& rhs)` and `(const std::string& lhs, const opDesc& rhs)` variants are useful. C++ aldready forces you to sprout 100 lines of code to move a matchstick, no point in adding more dead code for decoration :).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was confused about the operators.

Comment: No problem there. I appreciate your help.